# Tips for using Google when looking for C stuff, rather than C++?

Tags: c

Whenever I'm trying to Google something like (random example) `c udp networking library` this is the kind of thing that pops up:

- Simple Reliable UDP C++ Libraries - Stack Overflow
- Networking Framework for C++ (UDP or TCP)? - Stack Overflow
- open-network - A clean, object-oriented network-library for C++ ...

That is, Google thinks I'm interested in C++ pages for this query. **I'm not.** Is there any way to guide Google towards C pages, rather than C++ pages?

Comment: udp library C -"C++" -"C#" -"objective C"

Answer (score 2):

Try

> c udp networking library -"c++" -"C#"

Comment: The problem is that this hard-filters any page that contains the phrase "C++", so for example it will filter out a page that says "This library has bindings for Python, Java and C++". So while this might help it's way too agressive. Try it yourself by Googling, in order: `log4c` and `log4c -"c++"`. The first query will find the official project, while the second one has it filtered out.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following expression:

```
 -"C++"
```

in your search string.

```
-string
```

is used by google to filter out the unwanted pages. See [here](http://websearch.about.com/library/cheatsheet/blgooglecheatsheet.htm) for other tips

Comment: The problem is that this hard-filters any page that contains the phrase "C++", so for example it will filter out a page that says "This library has bindings for Python, Java and C++". So while this might help it's way too agressive. Try it yourself by Googling, in order: `log4c` and `log4c -"c++"`. The first query will find the official project, while the second one has it filtered out.

Comment: Yep you are right, but I don't think that Google implemented something like word "priority" or similar..But since in this world nothing is certain, I'm also interested on this topic..+1 to the quest

Answer (score 0):

You can help hint that you want C only by surrounding it in quotes like so:

```
udp library "C"
```

While this doesn't completely solve this nagging problem, it does HELP in SOME searches.

Usually, more C-specific results will be in the first page, and in some cases, where you usually only get  C++/C# stuff, you'll get one or two proper C results.

also notice that putting "C" at the beginning or the end doesn't always prioritize results the same way... (try both ;-)